# is there a way to capture creation and removal of element on web page?

Tags: javascript, events

is there a way to capture creation and removal of element on web page. for example: listening to the body tag, I can capture what element is created and removed under it and having a callback to handle something else when these events happen. thanks for any advice.

Comment: The opposite of "removing an element from the DOM" is "adding an element to the DOM", not "creating an element". New DOM elements are created independently from the DOM (via `createElement()`), and then added to the DOM in a separate command.

Comment: @Felix: Except that question is Firefox-specific.

Comment: @felix: that looks a good reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers (read: not IE) support this through the [DOMNodeInserted](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/#t16) and [DOMNodeRemoved](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/#t17) events.

Comment: this is very close to what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think the jquery [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin can do what you want.

Comment: this is a good plugin to use when I know what event type should be used.

Comment: It works without events as well. Can set a function to run when matching elements are added and removed from the page.